# PageSpeed Tools(Leverage browser caching)

Tags: http, google-pagespeed

How can fix this?:

Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:

http://query.yahooapis.com/…rmat=json&_nocache=1189031&callback=ywcb (3.3 minutes) https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false (30 minutes)

Comment: What do you want to *fix*? Please clarify

Comment: When I test experimental website(... .com) on PageSpeed  tools the result is show as I mentioned above. I must modified .htaccess(cache-control)  for these URLs but I don't know exact how.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't Fix this issue**. Google Page Speed wants you to increase cached max-age of these JS files. Now the problem here is, these files are hosted on servers that you don't control, meaning you cannot set http headers on these files.

check this similar article [PageSpeed review and optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154763/pagespeed-review-and-optimization)